# Convert multiple Columns to rows in comma delimited csv

Tags: sed, awk

I want to convert multiple Columns to rows.

e.g

Input :

```
 A,0,10,12,14,16,2,
 B,10,10P
```

Output:

```
 A,0,0
 A,10,10
 A,12,12
 A,14,14
 A,16,16
 A,2,2
 B,10,10
 B,10P,10p
```

I tried but not sure how to repeat the certain columns.

```
awk '{FS=",";OFS="\n"}{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' filename
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (i=2;i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i, $i}' file
A,0,0
A,10,10
A,12,12
A,14,14
A,16,16
A,2,2
B,10,10
B,10P,10P
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` set input and output field separator as comma.
- `for (i=2;i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i, $i` loop through all fields from 2nd, printing the first field plus the i-th twice.

Note that your attempt `awk '{FS=",";OFS="\n"}{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' filename` was setting `FS` and `OFS` on every line, while it's better to do it once, in the `BEGIN{}` block.

Comment: Setting FS as the OP did also wouldn't work for the first line, it's GOT to be done in BEGIN (or elsewhere before the first line of the file is read).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]+)(,[^,]+)/&\2\n\1/;//P;D' file
```